# TypeScript | Interfaces with endpoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I need to construct an interface in TS as part of my `dto`, that has the following properties.

```
interface IFace {
  something.else.more: string;
  something.else.thing: string;
  another.thing.here: number;
}
```

But I get some errors. So, this is what I did:

```
    interface IFace {
      "something.else.more": string;
      "something.else.thing": string;
      "another.thing.here": number;
    }
```

I am wondering if I am writing it correctly. And if not, how should this `dto` be written?

Comment: Yes this is the right way to do it

Comment: Why using dot in names? It's more burden for client code (`face["a.b.c"]`) and confusing (`face.a` possible?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a requirement in JavaScript that any object keys or variable names which don't contain the default character set (alphabet and numbers, `$` and `_`) must be stringified.

So yes, this is the correct way:

```
interface IFace {
  "something.else.more": string;
  "something.else.thing": string;
  "another.thing.here": number;
}
```